# How to insert "-" (hyphon symbol) with in a vector character in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
a <- "20160402"
```

I want to insert a "-" symbol in positions 5 and 8.

The result should like this

```
"2016-04-02"
```

I was trying to use `ins(a, "-", pos = c(5,8))

But this has not worked. Can anyone please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily do the conversion with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(a)
#[1] "2016-04-02 UTC"
```

---

Or use the correct format with `as.Date`

```
as.Date(a, '%Y%m%d')
#[1] "2016-04-02"
```

---

If we are looking for a regex solution, capture the characters as a group and use the backreference as the replacement

```
sub('(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})', '\\1-\\2-\\3', a)
#[1] "2016-04-02"
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer. It worked as always as any other answers from you. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes. I have opted for the second one as i could understand it easily. Thanks again

Comment: @Arun Thank you for the feedback.  Glad to help you again.